# In Codeigniter how to decode UTF-8 hex string into proper English

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8

I have search feature with codeigniter framework, today i've noticed some peoples are passing character strings like **Á, ú, ç, é**

When input passed by codeigniter core input, it converts into **%C3%81, %C3%BA, %C3%A7, %C3%A9** , i used following codeigniter helper.

```
$this->load->helper('text');

convert_accented_characters('è'); // output: e
```

it convert è into e, but how i can convert **UTF-8 - HEX** **'%C3%A9' or 'c3a9'** into proper English character like **A, u, c, e**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your PHP version is greater than or equal to 5.4, you can try Transliterator class.

```
$transliterator = Transliterator::createFromRules(':: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: NFC;', Transliterator::FORWARD);
    $test = ['Á', 'ú', 'ç', 'é','Áúçé'];
    foreach($test as $e) {
        $normalized = $transliterator->transliterate($e);
        echo $e. ' --> '.$normalized."\r\n";
    }
```

Output:

```
Á --> A ú --> u ç --> c é --> e Áúçé --> Auce
```

*By default it will be disabled. It should be enabled in php.ini file to use this feature.

**Update**:

Seems like your data is URL encoded. So you have to use `urlencode` function

```
urldecode("%C3%81, %C3%BA, %C3%A7, %C3%A9"); // Á, ú, ç, é
```

Then you can use CI feature to convert `è` into `e`, already you are using it

```
convert_accented_characters('è'); // output: e
```

Comment: i have character in hex, like : %C3%81, %C3%BA, %C3%A7, %C3%A9, problem is how i can convert following hex codes in proper character,

Comment: Updated my answer. Check, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's built-in function for UTF-8 decoding:

```
utf8_decode(string);
```

Comment: i have tried, echo utf8_decode('c3a9'); its not convert hex into character.